# Evaluating a limit that involves a summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

I was solving a physics problem and I got this expression:

$E=\lim_{N \to \infty}\left[\dfrac{k_0Q}{2R^2}\dfrac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N/2-1}\left(\sec{\dfrac{i\pi}{N}}\right)\right]$

I'm not sure that the following steps are valid:

$E=\dfrac{k_0Q}{2R^2}\left[\lim_{N \to \infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{N} \right)\right]\left[\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\lim_{N \to \infty}(N/2-1)}\left[\lim_{N \to \infty}\left(\sec{\dfrac{i\pi}{N}}\right)\right]\right]$

$E=\dfrac{k_0Q}{2R^2}\left[\lim_{N \to \infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{N} \right)\right]\left[\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\lim_{N \to \infty}(N/2-1)} (1)\right]$

$E=\dfrac{k_0Q}{2R^2}\left[\lim_{N \to \infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{N} \right)\right]\left[\lim_{N \to \infty}(N/2-1)\right]$

$E=\dfrac{k_0Q}{2R^2}\left[\lim_{N \to \infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{N} \right)\left(\dfrac{N}{2}-1\right)\right]$

$E=\dfrac{k_0Q}{2R^2}\left[\lim_{N \to \infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{1}{N} \right)\right]$

$E=\dfrac{k_0Q}{4R^2}$

Is it right?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's right. $E=\frac{k_0 Q}{2R^2}\int_0^{1/2} \sec(x\pi)dx$.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on ^'s correct answer: the equality

$$\lim a_{n}b_{n}=\lim a_{n}\lim b_{n}$$

is only guaranteed to hold when the two limits on the right exist and are finite. So your first step is not valid, since

$$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{i=0}^{N/2-1}\sec\left(\frac{i\pi}{N}\right)=\infty.$$

The trick here is that 
$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=0}^{N/2-1}\sec\left(\frac{i\pi}{N}\right)$$

is a left-endpoint Riemman sum for $$\int_{0}^{1/2}\sec(x)\;dx.$$

so your answer is your leading coefficient times the value of that integral (which I think is $\infty$).